# Can circuit breaking be done for TCP services using Istio 0.8.0?

Tags: istio

I am trying to implement circuit breaking scenario. I wanted to know if it can be done for TCP services as there is a max tcp connection in the traffic policy.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: httpbin
  ...
spec:
  host: httpbin
  trafficPolicy:
    connectionPool:
      http:
        http1MaxPendingRequests: 1
        maxRequestsPerConnection: 1
      tcp:
        maxConnections: 100
    outlierDetection:
      http:
        baseEjectionTime: 180.000s
        consecutiveErrors: 1
        interval: 1.000s
        maxEjectionPercent: 100
```

Also, I tried to collect a tcp service metric and was able to. I can view the metric in prometheus. I am quite new to this and trying to explore. But is there a way to bring the metric to the service mesh?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify - when you say circuit breaking, do you specifically mean outlier detection?

Comment: Yes. I meant outlier detection and I believe that the support is coming soon.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your assumption about future support for TCP services is correct. If I'm understanding the [networking.v1alpha3 docs](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#OutlierDetection) correctly, then (at the time of writing this) Istio 0.8.0 only seems to support outlier detection for HTTP services:

> A Circuit breaker implementation that tracks the status of each individual host in the upstream service. While currently applicable to only HTTP services, future versions will support opaque TCP services as well.